# Is there a way to limit the size of mobile viewports?

Tags: html, css, mobile, viewport

I am having some issues with my viewport on the mobile version of my web site. All of my elements display and are re-sized correctly within the page, however the page extends much farther then the end of the content.

Is there a way to restrict the height of my view port? Or could this possibly be a different issue I am just not seeing?

After further testing this error only occurs on Android mobile devices. Are there any know issues with Android viewports?

Comment: Probably another issue.  Can you link the problem page?

Comment: www.blockdot.com - In landscape format

Comment: I am not seeing any height issues on my iphone, but I am seeing some width issues.  Are you setting hard width values for the html/body/section tags?

Comment: Interesting. I am using '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>' It seems I need to do some more testing.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `height=device-height,` from

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent" />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

this is i found in your code

if you `height=device-height,` will fit the site vertical on the screen

may be you required the

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

only